# How to make loop run as many times as user inputs?

Tags: java, loops, for-loop

I have a for loop and the method to call it is printMe() and I want the user to be able to determine how many times it runs with their input. This is along the lines of what I think it should be:

```
  System.out.println("Enter a number: ");
  loop = input.nextInt();
```

Comment: did you get it working?

Comment: Hi Itamar Green, I got the cannot find symbol for input when I tried to integrate your code.

Comment: The name of the `Scanner` object needs to be the same as the one used to call `.nextInt()`.

Comment: No error now, but when I input the number of times I want the for loop method to work, it still only does it once?

Comment: what is the code you're using? please edit your question

Comment: Works now, thank Itamar! I'd up vote your post but I'm new here so it won't let me.

Comment: Odd. why can't you?

Comment: Oh wait, it lets me now. Thank you once again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
int loop = input.nextInt();
for(int i = 0; i<loop;i++){
    //do the thing
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Read the user input thanks to a scanner

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
int loopNum = sc.nextInt();
for (int i=); i<loopNum; i++){
    printMe();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Should be something like:

```
for (int i=0; i<loopNum; i++)
  printMe();
```

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

yes it is correct if your variable input from class `Scanner`. You can declare variable `sc` like this and call it many times if you want to read more input from users.

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in); 
System.out.println("Enter a number: ");
loopNum = sc.nextInt();
```